# Adobe Photoshop running script for multiple layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, cs6, photoshop-scripting, actions

I have 103 layers which i need to save as PNG files(each layer individually) but the problem I'm haiving is;the background layer (is to be saved with each layer) how can i do this ? Kindly guide me thanks

Comment: Not a real answer but sometimes I think the best way is to just do it. I usually calculate the time, let's say 20 seconds to save 1 layer. For 100 layers that would be about half an hour. You asked the question 1 hour ago, so you already wasted 2X time.

Comment: What do you mean by 'guide' exactly? What have you tried, what didn't work?

Comment: Hi Welcome to GDSE. Why did you create a document with 103 layered PNGs?  If you had the images as individual PNGs, you could probably have done this with a simple Action, and then used File > Automate > Batch to apply it to each PNG.

Comment: @sergey kritskiy. I tried running a script>export layers to file, but the layers kept on getting saved as PNG without the background layer

Comment: @billy ker . Thanks for the greet . I created this document because its a t-shirt mock-up. I have a t-shirt placed as the base layer and the 103 layers are t-shirt designs which i have to save individually keeping the base layer attached.

Comment: @komental sir i am a newbie . Not possible for me to save a layer within 20 seconds

Comment: @AmmarAhmed - yeah, that's what I mean. You've kind of done it backwards, because now you'll need a script, when it would have been much easier to just record an Action to place the t-shirt under one PNG instead, then process the whole batch of PNG images with the Action.

Comment: @billy kerr- Thanks alot sir. I'll definitely do it like this for the next file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way: use an action to quickly convert layer pairs to single layers. And then use Export > Layers to Files.

[image]

### Setting up the layer-merging action

This action deletes layers once used, so only run it on a duplicate of your PSD.

Recording the action can be tricky, as selecting layers in the layers panel often creates layer-specific actions. To avoid recording layer-specific actions (MacOS shortcuts shown):

- Merge visible: <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
- Hide current layer: <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
- Select backward layer: <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>
- Delete layer: <kbd>delete</kbd>
- Move current layer: <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>
- Select forward layer: <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>

The layer-merging action, along with the before and after just one run-through, is shown below.

[image]

Now you just need to run the layer-merging action 103 times. To make this bit easier, you can create another action that just runs the layer-merging action a set number of times.

[image]